# Get locked tables in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Is there any way via a MySQL query to get the locked tables?  I have a C# threading application running and there are bunch of tables getting locked in the app.

I need to see the locked tables and analyze the code that could be locking it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES
```

An check whether the column `In_use` is greater than 0. In that case, the table is locked.

## Examples

- List of locked tables:

  `show open tables WHERE In_use > 0`
- Check whether the table `tb_employees` is locked or not:

  `show open tables WHERE Table LIKE 'tb_employees' AND In_use > 0`

From the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-open-tables.html):

> **`In_use`**
>
> > The number of table locks or
> >     lock requests there are for the table.
> >     For example, if one client acquires a
> >     lock for a table using LOCK TABLE t1
> >     WRITE, In_use will be 1. If another
> >     client issues LOCK TABLE t1 WRITE
> >     while the table remains locked, the
> >     client will block waiting for the
> >     lock, but the lock request causes
> >     In_use to be 2. If the count is zero,
> >     the table is open but not currently
> >     being used. In_use is also increased
> >     by the HANDLER ... OPEN statement and
> >     decreased by HANDLER ... CLOSE.

Comment: Thanks cristian, looks perfect.