# mysql: locked table but none open

Tags: mysql

I have a looked table:

```
mysql> show status like '%\_locks\_%';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| Table_locks_immediate | 59137 |
| Table_locks_waited    | 1     |
+-----------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230693/get-locked-tables-in-mysql-query) to see what it, but there is nothing opened:

```
mysql> show open tables WHERE In_use > 0;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Is this normal? Is there a trick to see what is locked here?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can analyze the table lock contention on your system by checking the Table_locks_immediate and Table_locks_waited status variables, which indicate the number of times that requests for table locks could be granted immediately and the number that had to wait, respectively.

it is the capacity and how many had to actually wait once