# How do you investigate contention issues on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am a website developer and I am being told by the server administrator that there are contention issues on the mysql database. I would like to investigate these contention issues myself and see what they are but I do not know how or where to look for contention issues. Please can you advise me where to look. Do I need to look in the logs? If so what logs and where will I find them? The database is MySQL v5.1 running on linux. I'm not sure what version yet as I don't have control panel or ssh access but I aim to get that today.

Thanks very much

Comment: What connection issue ? What error message its showing ?

Answer (score 2):

Contention issues is usually a fancy way of saying there are locking problems, meaning queries get locked status. 
You need to identify them and check your app for solutions.

You can run [SHOW PROCESSLIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html) when server is busy to see what queries are currently locked.

[SHOW OPEN TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-open-tables.html) can also help you to identify the problem and [another question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230693/get-locked-tables-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 1):

First you should check the mysql is running or not by using below command.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

This command will show :-

```
Enter password:
Uptime: 4  Threads: 1  Questions: 62  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 51  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 60  Queries per second avg: 15.200
```

Also check the error type :-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should *start* by asking your server administrator what he/she sees that makes him/her believe that there are contention issues - they have a much better view of your DBMS than we do. And by the sound of things you are paying them for this service.

It would have been helpful if you'd said which database engine the tables are stored in: this is by far the most critical issue for contention in MySQL. You may be able to solve your problems by switching from MyISAM to Innodb.

> I don't have control panel or ssh access

IME off-the-shelf control panels are fine for (very) rudimentary admin tasks, but not much use for this.

I would start by looking at the slow query log. This should be configured to log *all* queries - if it's not tell the admin you need it changed. Look at which queries have high lock times, then identify the lonf executing queries which are causing the high lock times. Then fix them.