# How do you know whether a MySQL table is locked or not?

Tags: mysql, locking

I'm trying to determine whether or not a query that I'm running is locking up the table that it's running against.

First off, I may be slightly misunderstanding the meaning or some of the nuance behind what *locking* means exactly.  What I'm primarily interested in is whether this query is going to block other reads/writes in such a way that other parts of my app will break when I run this query.

For example, let's say that the query is for the order table in an ecommerce app.  I want to avoid locking up the order table in such a way that orders are going to be blocked from being placed.

I've read this answer where it shows how to get a list of tables that are "locked" based on the `In_use` column:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230723/1117286

I've verified that while my query is running, `In_use` does change from `0` to `1` for the table in question.  The `Name_locked` column stays at `0` though - not sure exactly what that means.

And, most importantly, I've tested `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` in my local development environment, *while the query is running* and the table is "locked", and all three have completed successfully.

Does this mean that the table is in use but not actually locked?

Comment: Is your table InnoDB or MyISAM - it makes a difference. InnoDB would queue the later statements and physically apply the changes after your query finishes, but this would be invisible to any other queries and so would look like the table is not locked. MyISAM will simply wait for any lock to release. Note that you can see queries waiting for locks using 'SHOW PROCESSLIST'.

Comment: Thanks Giles!  They're InnoDB.  I'm pretty sure the query isn't even being queued though b/c it completes before the longer running query does.  It completes just about as fast as it would without the longer running query running at all.

Comment: Yes, that`s the "transactional" part of innodb at work (which MyISAM is not). The later queries are recorded but not necessarily stored in the table, any queries that come along after those see the data as if the in-between queries have been committed. InnoDB does not lock a table for reads, so if this is not an insert/update/delete you will not lock anything. Writes use row-locking so will only lock  other queries if they access the same row. Take a look here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Comment: In hindsight I think the correct answer to your question "Does this mean that the table is in use but not actually locked?" is "Yes" :)

Comment: Thanks man, you rock.  So basically a read can never lock an InnoDB table?

Comment: Yes, in innodb you pretty much have to issue a lock table to get any lock.

Answer (score 0):

Locks on tables are visible in the performance_schema, in MySQL 5.7

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/metadata-locks-table.html